# How to remove word wrap from textarea?

Tags: html, textarea, word-wrap

my simple textarea doesn't show a horizontal bar when text overflows. It wraps text for a new line. So how do I remove wordwrap and display horizontal bar when text overflows?

Comment: Do you mean on HTML? Swing? something else?

Comment: Added HTML tag to avoid that confusion, but I'm only guessing by the current answers.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Textareas shouldn't wrap by default, but you can set wrap="soft" to explicitly disable wrap:

```
<textarea name="nowrap" cols="30" rows="3" wrap="soft"></textarea>
```

<strike>EDIT: The "wrap" attribute is not officially supported. I got it from [the german SELFHTML page](http://de.selfhtml.org/navigation/suche/index.htm?Suchanfrage=textarea) (an english source is [here](http://www.idocs.com/tags/forms/_TEXTAREA_WRAP.html)) that says IE 4.0 and Netscape 2.0 support it. I also tested it in FF 3.0.7 where it works as supposed.</strike> Things have changed here, SELFHTML is now a wiki and the english source link is dead.

EDIT2: If you want to be sure every browser supports it, you can use CSS to change wrap behaviour:

> Using Cascading Style Sheets (CSS), you can achieve the same effect with
>   `white-space: nowrap;  overflow: auto;`.
>   Thus, the wrap attribute can be regarded as outdated.

From [here](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/textarea.html) (seems to be an excellent page with information about textarea).

EDIT3: I'm not sure when it changed (according to the comments, must've been around 2014), but `wrap` is now an official HTML5 attribute, see [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_wrap.asp). Changed the answer to match this.

Comment: wrap seems not a textarea properties... or maybe it deprecated?
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

Comment: Yes, it seems it's unofficial - thanks for the hint, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: The "wrap" attribute works in Firefox 3.6, but isn't valid HTML5. However, the CSS solution doesn't work, as if "white-space:nowrap" is ignored.

Comment: To add to @clint-pachl, you cannot change the value of the `wrap` property once the textarea has been rendered.

Comment: One more interesting attribute is http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp, where chrome uses the undocumented "break-all" value for a textarea. Trying this on a div didn't work for me (to get it to wrap).

Comment: FireFox 18 still seems to be ignoring the CSS "white-space" property for textarea atleast. IE 9 stop the wrapping but I couldn't find a "white-space" value to allow you to enter a new line. The HTML attribute wrap="off" though seems to be supported by both (and from what I've read, all other major browsers), though IE does paint in disabled scroll bars by default and enables them as required, so the CSS overflow:auto; is stil desirable. Would have liked a purely CSS solution but I think the white-space property is more concerned with pre-existing content and not user input.

Comment: `white-space: pre;` (or `pre-line`/`pre-wrap`) had the same affect as `wrap="off"` for me (whereas `white-space: nowrap` didn't respect the `padding`)

Comment: @ClintPachl Actually, `wrap` is valid HTML5... it's settings are now `"hard"` and `"soft"` ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#attr-wrap))

Comment: @Mottie It would be much better to link to current version of HTML5 specification than to Mozilla docs. Here's the link for current version – http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140731/forms.html#attr-textarea-wrap

Comment: `white-space: nowrap` is *eevil*, it collapses white spaces!
http://jsfiddle.net/3zsvbsdo/6/

(at least in chrome)...

Comment: @FlashThunder: Thanks, changed the answer to reflect some changes (SELFHTML, dead links, wrap being official HTML5 with `soft`/`hard` values now)

Comment: "Textareas shouldn't wrap by default" [citation needed], I just tried IE10, Chrome 45.0.2454.93, FF 38 ESR, all of them wrap by default when you start typing or when you put text in:  https://jsfiddle.net/502qycsn/

Comment: The only way I could get IE 9 - 11 to behave like the other browsers was wrap="off". wrap="soft" had no effect.

Comment: `wrap="off"` is no longer valid however it is requirement for both IE and Edge!

Comment: `wrap="soft"` does nothing in Chrome 86. `wrap="off"` was needed.

Answer (score 206):

```
textarea {
  white-space: pre;
  overflow-wrap: normal;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

`white-space: nowrap` also works if you don't care about whitespace, but of course you don't want that if you're working with code (or indented paragraphs or any content where there might deliberately be multiple spaces) ... so i prefer `pre`.

`overflow-wrap: normal` (was `word-wrap` in older browsers) is needed in case some parent has changed that setting; it can cause wrapping even if `pre` is set.

also -- contrary to the currently accepted answer -- textareas **do** often wrap by default. `pre-wrap` seems to be the default on my browser.

Comment: With FF 20, you still need wrap="off" in the html textarea tag!  This technology is such inconsistent crap.

Comment: +1 for providing a CSS solution and pointing out that textareas DO wrap by default

Comment: `word-wrap` has since been renamed to `overflow-wrap` (`word-wrap` being a widely implemented "alternate name"): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap

Comment: Works on Chrome 36, fails on Firefox 31: http://jsfiddle.net/cirosantilli/t8j1kcya/

Comment: Ah, there seems to be a feature request on Firefox from 2001 but with some recent (2014) supporting comments for Chrome behavior by dev Ehsan Akhgari: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=82711 . Go and upvote it!

Comment: This now works in Firefox (Aurora channel, v36) - see http://jsfiddle.net/mlhDevelopment/gvjy14xu/ the green textarea.

Comment: Confirmed working in Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit) as of Dec 23rd 2015.

Comment: Thanks! Tested and working in Chrome 51, Firefox 38, IE 11 and Edge.

Comment: Personally, I think it's better to replace `overflow-x: scroll` with `overflow: auto`. The scroll bars reduce the available typing space in the text area. Also, IE11 rendered a vertical scroll bar unnecessarily with your way, but `overflow: auto` fixed it.

Answer (score 22):

The following CSS based solution works for me:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style type='text/css'>
   textarea {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:    scroll;
    overflow-y:  hidden;
    overflow-x:  scroll;
    overflow:    -moz-scrollbars-horizontal;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form>
   <textarea>This is a long line of text for testing purposes...</textarea>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 17):

I found a way to make a textarea with all this working at the same time:

- With horizontal scrollbar
- Supporting multiline text
- Text not wrapping

It works well on:

- Chrome 15.0.874.120
- Firefox 7.0.1
- Opera 11.52 (1100)
- Safari 5.1 (7534.50)
- IE 8.0.6001.18702

Let me explain how i get to that: I was using Chrome inspector integrated tool and I saw values on CSS styles, so I try these values, instead of normal ones... trial & errors till I got it reduced to minimum and here it is for anyone that wants it.

In the CSS section I used just this for Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari:

```
textarea {
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

In the CSS section I used just this for IE:

```
textarea {
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

It was a bit tricky, but there is the CSS.

An (x)HTML tag like this:

```
<textarea id="myTextarea" rows="10" cols="15"></textarea>
```

And at the end of the  `<head>` section a JavaScript like this:

```
 window.onload=function(){
   document.getElementById("myTextarea").wrap='off';
 }
```

The JavaScript is for making the W3C validator passing XHTML 1.1 Strict, since the wrap attribute is not official and thus cannot be an (x)HTML tag directly, but most browsers handle it, so after loading the page it sets that attribute.

Hope this can be tested on more browsers and versions and help someone to improve it and makes it fully cross-browser for all versions.

Comment: +1 .wrap='off' is the magic that did the trick in FF 14.0.1... Thanks.

Comment: The JavaScript does not seem to work on Safari 5.0.6 (Last PPC version), even though you can use wrap="off" in the HTML.

Comment: .wrap is what did it for me, using Chrome. I also used it in conjunction with the no-wrap in css.

Comment: wrap='off' made IE behave like the other browsers.

Answer (score 6):

This question seems to be the most popular one for disabling `textarea` wrap.  However, as of April 2017 I find that **IE 11** (11.0.9600) will **not** disable word wrap with any of the above solutions.

The *only* solution which does work for IE 11 is `wrap="off"`.  `wrap="soft"` and/or the various CSS attributes like `white-space: pre` alter where IE 11 chooses to wrap but it still wraps somewhere.  Note that I have tested this with or without **Compatibility View**.  IE 11 is pretty HTML 5 compatible, but not in this case.

Thus, to achieve lines which retain their whitespace and go off the right-hand side I am using:

```
<textarea style="white-space: pre; overflow: scroll;" wrap="off">
```

Fortuitously this does seem to work in Chrome & Firefox too.  I am not defending the use of pre-HTML 5 `wrap="off"`, just saying that it seems to be required for IE 11.

Comment: Nice one, saved my day! Was breaking my head over why programmatically adding newlines failed using the code from the accepted answer.

Comment: This IE bug has also been transferred to Edge

Answer (score 4):

If you can use JavaScript, the following might be the most portable option today (tested Firefox 31, Chrome 36):

- a div with `contenteditable="true"`
- the styles suggested by Partly
- JavaScript form submission on button click: [How to submit a form using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855656/how-to-submit-a-form-using-javascript)

http://jsfiddle.net/cirosantilli/eaxgesoq/

```
<style>
  div#editor {
    white-space: pre;
    word-wrap: normal;
    overflow-x: scroll;
  }
<style>
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

There seems to be no standard, portable CSS solution:

- `wrap` attribute is not standard
- `white-space: pre;` does not work for Firefox 31 for `textarea`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cirosantilli/t8j1kcya/), [open feature request](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=82711).

Also, if you can use Javascript, you might as well use the ACE editor:

http://jsfiddle.net/cirosantilli/bL9vr8o8/

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.1.3/ace.js"></script>
<div id="editor">content</div>
<script>
  var editor = ace.edit('editor')
  editor.renderer.setShowGutter(false)
</script>
```

Probably works with ACE because it does not use a `textarea` either which is underspecified / incoherently implemented, but not sure if it is uses `contenteditable`.

Comment: +1 Out of all the answers here, the CSS here is the only one that works reliably on both Chrome and Safari's textarea. Other answers just work on Chrome only