# Cross browser CSS wrap="off"

Tags: css, textarea

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how remove wordwrap from textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657795/how-remove-wordwrap-from-textarea)

Can't figure out how to disable word wrapping in texarea.
What is the CSS equivalent of wrap="off" cross browser?

Comment: This was already answerd [how remove wordwrap from textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657795/how-remove-wordwrap-from-textarea)

Answer (score -1):

```
<textarea name="nowrap" cols="20" rows="5" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:auto;"></textarea>
```

Comment: With white-space:nowrap you can't start a new line by hitting Enter key.