# How to force single line in a HTML textarea element?

Tags: html, webforms, forms

Is there a way to make a HTML textarea element to allow only one line?

I want to do this because I will have a button to expand it, but if user is allowed to enter multiple lines when the textarea is not expanded (only 1 row) it doesn look very nice, and if I use a textbox for the not expanded state, it looks weird when I replace it with the textarea and expand it with animation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how remove wordwrap from textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657795/how-remove-wordwrap-from-textarea)

Comment: No, my question have nothing to do with carriage returns, but with new lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put jQuery to use to create such field effect. [See the demo here](http://demos.9lessons.info/updateshow.html).

http://www.9lessons.info/2010/03/facebook-like-expanding-textbox-with.html

Answer (score 1):

No.

You can *stack the elements*, then show the textarea first and remove the textbox right away. I guess it would be the workaround.

Example on [how to stack elements on jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/gRCVb/).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you'd need to use javascript to monitor and prevent the enter key.

Answer (score -1):

Not in plain HTML, however, if you use JavaScript you could do it.