# Textarea horiz. scrollbar not applying

Tags: html, css, textarea, scrollbar

I have a textarea that contains code. The problem is, that in order for it to look good, the Textarea has to stop wrapping the text, and use a Horizontal Scrollbar instead.

I tried this:

```
textarea
{
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow:-moz-scrollbars-horizontal;

}
```

and this:

```
textarea
{

    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow:-moz-scrollbars-horizontal;

}
```

However the Horizontal Scrollbar is not applying.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the `wrap` attribute to `off`

```
<textarea wrap="off"></textarea>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wesley_murch/HZkLK/

There is also a `soft` and `hard` value for `wrap`. The only decent reference on this I found on [tizag.com](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmltextarea.php), although there must be better ones out there. From the linked page:

> The wrap attribute refers to how the
>   text reacts when it reaches the end of
>   each row in the text field. Wrapping
>   can be one of three settings:
>
> ```
> soft
> hard
> off
> ```
>
> Soft forces the words to wrap once
>   inside the text area but when the form
>   is submitted, the words will no longer
>   appear as such (Line breaks will not
>   be added).
>
> Hard wraps the words inside the text
>   box and places line breaks at the end
>   of each line so that when the form is
>   submitted it appears exactly as it
>   does in the text box.
>
> Off sets a textarea to ignore all
>   wrapping and places the text into one
>   ongoing line.

I'm not sure about HTML5, but this won't validate in XHTML or HTML4 (the validator tells me: there is no attribute "WRAP"), but it does certainly seem to work in the following browsers I checked:

- Firefox 4
- IE6, IE7, IE8
- Chrome 10
- Opera 11
- Safari 5.0.3

I don't *think* this can be done cross-browser with CSS. I was coming up short trying to find official docs/support for this, and when I *did* find something useful, it was here on Stack Overflow!

See this answer for more details:

[How remove word wrap from textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657795/how-remove-wordwrap-from-textarea/657811#657811)

However, the CSS solution provided there is not working for me on Firefox 4...

Comment: HTMl has a wrap attribute? Is this specs? Just want to know!

Comment: @Jawad: Not officially, but it does work. You'll have to sacrifice a validation error.

Answer (score 2):

```
textarea
{
 white-space:nowrap;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rpA3C/)

Comment: This isn't doing anything for me in FF4, but seems to work in IE8 and Chrome. It's interesting, I've run into some other Firefox rendering oddities lately, but I usually consider FF to be the browser that "has it right". I think I need to reconsider this perspective.

Comment: Yeah That is strange. Eventhough the docs says FF supports it - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/white-space

Comment: The CSS property itself is supported, it's just not working in a textarea.

Comment: Yup. Wesley's above answer is the way to go than. But, as he said, "You'll have to sacrifice a validation error"

Comment: Also: `textarea {white-space: pre}`

Answer (score 0):

MDN says explicitly that `wrap="off"` (the current accepted answer) is equivalent to setting `white-space: pre` in CSS, so that's the ideal way to do it at present if you can't set the `wrap` attribute, or don't want to since it's technically invalid. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea.

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191109/textarea-horiz-scrollbar-not-applying#answer-6191185) says to use `white-space: nowrap`, but this has unexpected consequences: it will collapse all the white space, including new lines, in the source text. Presumably since you're not using an `<input>` you want the user to be able to enter text with multiple lines and preserve spaces.

So what you probably actually want is

```
white-space: pre;
```

It will preserve all the white space in the `<textarea>`, but make it stop wrapping.

See the MDN documentation for more on the different `white-space` options: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: In my opinion this is actually the best answer here. I'm going to make an edit to give it a little more information and explain what it's doing and why it's better than the other answers.