# How to stop a textarea from word wrapping?

Tags: html, css, textarea, word-wrap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how remove wordwrap from textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657795/how-remove-wordwrap-from-textarea)

Is it possible to stop a textarea element widget from word-wrapping?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set it to wrap to "off":

```
<textarea name="abc" wrap="off"></textarea>
```

Yup - [How remove word wrap from textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657795/how-remove-wordwrap-from-textarea) explains it better.

Comment: Duplicate yes, but due to the nuances, this one was the better answer for me.