# How to remove the "automatic new line" on textarea

Tags: jquery, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how remove wordwrap from textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657795/how-remove-wordwrap-from-textarea)

I have a text area :

```
<textarea id="areaTL" style='width:700px; height:400px;></textarea>
```

and I'd like to do a newline only when there is a `\n` into the text, so the horizontal scroll should be larger than the max text inside the textarea.

Tried with :

```
overflow: scroll; wrap="off"'
```

but seems it doesnt works. I'd like to do it for Chome/Firefox and IE7+.

How can I do it?

**EDIT**

Using `white-space:nowrap;` as suggested I get this working, but if I do :

```
textArea=$('#areaTL').val().split('\n');
```

I get only 1 element in the array, not N. Why?

Comment: @The Mask Your duplicate comment is a duplicate as well. :)

Comment: @Shi OverZealous is an ninja. :)

Comment: @markzzz Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Shi : Chrome, Firefox, IE7+... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe `white-space:nowrap;` is what you're looking for instead of `wrap`.

Comment: Here's a fiddle with it: http://jsfiddle.net/EkwgM/

Comment: But after there is a problem with this. If I set white-space:nowrap; and I do `textArea=$('#areaTL').val().split('\n');` I'll get only 1 line on my array. Why?

Comment: This works with Webkit, but not in Firefox 5.

Comment: You'd somehow have to find the `\n` while the content is being typed and then append a `<br />` after it.

Answer (score 0):

try this it should work

```
<textarea cols=100 rows=5 wrap='off'>
```