# Avoiding wrap in textarea

Tags: html, textarea

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how remove wordwrap from textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657795/how-remove-wordwrap-from-textarea)

I have a textarea which I fill in PHP (I'm reading the text from a text file).

Now, if the text is longer than the text-area, it wraps it instead of showing a horizontal scroll bar. And I want to change this.

I've tried those possibilities in CSS, and none of them worked:

```
overflow: auto
overflow: scroll
overflow-x: scroll
```

Can somebody help please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use `wrap="off"` attribute:](http://www.idocs.com/tags/forms/_TEXTAREA_WRAP.html)

```
<textarea wrap="off"></textarea>
```

Comment: `wrap="off"` is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`textarea@wrap`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-button-element.html#attr-textarea-wrap):

```
<textarea wrap="hard" cols="2"></textarea>
```

`wrap="soft"` is the default.

> The `wrap` attribute is an enumerated attribute with two keywords and
>   states: the `soft` keyword which maps to the Soft state, and the `hard`
>   keyword which maps to the Hard state. The missing value default is the
>   Soft state.
>
> The Soft state indicates that the text in the `textarea` is not to be
>   wrapped when it is submitted (though it can still be wrapped in the
>   rendering).
>
> The Hard state indicates that the text in the textarea is to have
>   newlines added by the user agent so that the text is wrapped when it
>   is submitted.
>
> If the element's `wrap` attribute is in the Hard state, the `cols`
>   attribute must be specified.