# Textarea needs ellipsis instead of word wrap

Tags: html, css

I need to know if any CSS Ninja out there can school me on how to do this. I have set up a JSFiddle with an example of what I am seeing.

It is a test area that has two line in it. Neither of the lines word wrap, but neither of them will ellipsis like I am asking them to. Perhaps it isn't possible.

http://jsfiddle.net/aaronfrost/PjuFB/

Comment: I'm guessing that text-overflow only applies to non-replaced elements.

Comment: Check the Compatability section of this page http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/white-space, doesnt look like you can do it in a textarea.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657795/how-remove-wordwrap-from-textarea, also updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PjuFB/14/ works in FF not sure on others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it imperative that you use a textarea itself?
You can make that one work using a `contenteditable` div and p tags for the lines

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <p class="wtf">
        WHAT IS HAPPENING asdfkjas dflkasd jfalskdfj asldkfj asldkf
    </p>
    <p class="wtf">
        SECOND LINE and it also needs to have an ellipsis
    </p>
</div>
```

[View fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/achusonline/PjuFB/13/)

Comment: the problem with this approach is that the words for each line, each `p` element gets cut off, instead of words getting pushed down to the next `p`, and then being cut off at the end of the containing element as a whole...