# How do I detectwhen a textarea is wrapping by width?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, textarea

I use the function below to control the maximum row of textarea.

```
<textarea wrap="hard" name="" class="jua" onkeydown="return limitLines(this, event)" id="text_01_01" rows="2" placeholder=""></textarea>
function limitLines(obj, e){
    console.log("test");
    let numberOfLines = (obj.value.match(/\n/g) || []).length + 1;
    let maxRow = obj.rows;
    if (e.which === 13 && numberOfLines === maxRow){
        return false;
    }
}
```

but this way, this method cannot detect line breaks by width.
I want to count even rows that automatically wrap.

Sorry for my poor English skills.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe determining the count of characters on a wrapped line is possible at all via JavaScript.  Wrapping is a purely visual behavior from the JS perspective.  I would suggest giving the `<textarea>` a static width and disable word wrap all together (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/657811/15580602)).