# Disable wrapping in a textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea

I am trying to stop disable in textarea.
I am working in a markdown previewer and I want to apply that. I try this methods but it didn't work:

```
<textarea name="nowrap" wrap="soft">Something</textarea>
<!-- and css method:-->
textarea {
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: [This previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/657811/21146235) has a fairly comprehensive survey of what's available

Comment: It doesn't work !

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Maybe the markdown previewer strips away styles and/or sanitises html props. Perhaps you could provide more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry! I find the solution myself. I need to add `readonly`. Example:

```css
textarea{
width: 350px;
background-color: #c0d8d8;
}
```

```html
<textarea readonly>Something is funny</textarea>
```