How to create a no-wrap multiline TextField in Flet?
I need to create a TextField that is multi-line, offers scroll (when multiple lines) but does not wrap long lines in Flet.
Actually it might be handy to offer a horizontal scroll when the lines are too long.

it seems the wrap attribute of HTML <textarea> is not supported by flet. You can use CSS to override flet defaults tho: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657795/how-to-remove-word-wrap-from-textarea

@Kaii not sure if the rendered GUI is an embedded WebWidget (and consequentially an HTML page) as I do not run Flet app against the web but as a standalone app in Linux
